# Append element in the array in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Schema for one of the node in firebase.

```
const item={
            username:this.state.username,
            userID:this.state.userID,
            status:this.state.status,
            email:this.state.email,
            createdDate:this.state.createdDate,
            subject:this.state.subject,
            message:[
                {
                    type:this.state.messageType,
                    data:this.state.message
                }
            ]
            
        }
```

All thinks work perfectly fine for me. But when I tries to push item in the message array, it's getting very difficult. I researched a lot and find that in firebase you can't do push elements similar to javascript or any other language. Now my problem is how to push item in the message array, or if not then is any other data structure which suit for my task.

Comment: I think you can clone the message array and push the element into cloned array then update this data in firebase.

Comment: @Rohitha can you please elaborate this is code.

Comment: Hope you are fetching the data initially at initial load and storing it in some state. Using that state you can find particular document and clone the message array. Update it as above mentioned and update the message something like this dbFirestore.collection('collectionName/' + id).update({
    message: updatedMessage
});
If you are not fetching initially then ignore this.